# boost::tcp::iostream read & write simultaneously

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I wish to implement a full-duplex tcp stream. Here is an example.

```
//server.cpp

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream SocketStream;

void ThreadA()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        std::string Line;
        std::getline(SocketStream, Line);    //Y
        std::cout << Line << std::endl;
    }
}

void ThreadB()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        std::string Line;
        std::getline(std::cin, Line);     //Z
        SocketStream<<Line<<std::endl;    //X
    }
}

int main()
{  
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    acceptor.accept(*SocketStream.rdbuf(), ec);

    boost::thread tA(ThreadA);
    boost::thread tB(ThreadB);
    tA.join(); 
    tB.join();
    return 0;
}

//client.cpp

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream SocketStream;

void ThreadA()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        std::string Line;
        std::getline(SocketStream, Line);    
        std::cout << Line << std::endl;
    }
}

void ThreadB()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        std::string Line;
        std::getline(std::cin, Line);     
        SocketStream<<Line<<std::endl;    
    }
}

int main()
{  
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    SocketStream.connect("127.0.0.1", "4444");

    boost::thread tA(ThreadA);
    //boost::thread tB(ThreadB);
    tA.join(); 
    //tB.join();
    return 0;
}
```

But it would block on line X.
**Q1**, am I doing something wrong or is `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream` simply incapable of doing this?
**Q2**, if `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream` is not enough to fulfill the mission, what else should I use?
I saw `boost::iostream` having a bidirectional mode. Is that what I'm looking for? I'm unfamiliar with `boost::iostream` so I'm not sure what it really does.
If `boost::iostream` fails too, then must I use `boost::asio`'s asynchronous operations? Cuz what I want is to make the socket really behave like a stream and wrapping asynchronous operations may be difficult.

**Additional:** What I wish is that the `SocketStream` can be written while it's also blocking at reading, which means that the stream is full-duplex.

Please, any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Which line is this blocking on? Can you show your code for initializing SocketStream?

Comment: Ok, next: how are you initiating threads?

Comment: The two parties in the session are both doing the same thing: a blocking receive followed by a blocking send.  How does either of them ever get past the blocking receive in the beginning?

Comment: How do you pass the SocketStream to each thread?

Comment: @SamMiller Oops, sorry for the mistake. The `SocketStream` is actually in a namespace. So basically it's global.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think after line Z get passed, line Y is blocking line X. So what I wish is that the stream can be written while it's blocking at reading.

Comment: I built your code on Mac OS X and Linux and it seems to work as advertised, no hangs. Can you update the question to include a stack trace when it is hung? What is your platform?

Comment: @SamMiller I have updated the question to show a complete example including client and server. I'm on win7 vs2010. As to the stack trace, I don't know how to do it here. But I think you would see the problem clearly running the complete example.

Comment: @SamMiller Also I don't think there might be anything OS specific here and you should be able to see the hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instances of `boost::asio` classes is not thread-safe (io_service is only the exception). So you can not use single instance of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream` in 2 threads.

To do this task i'd prefer to use async operations and additional thread to read **stdin** since this read is blocking. So, one of threads doing **getline** from stdin and **asio::write** to peer. Other thread working with **async_read_until** to read until `\r\n` is recevied. Also, your server seems cannot work with more than one peer, so you will be able to deal with this using **async_accept**

Comment: Thank you and upvoted. Do you mean that it's impossible to use iostream style to achieve the purpose here?

Comment: @Immueggpain i dont have experience using iostream style, but i think it is not thread safe, so you cannot use it in many threads.

Comment: Then is it possible to use `boost::iostream` with `boost::asio` to create stream-like interfaces? I'm currently using 2 `tcp::stream`s but that means 2 tcp connections...

Comment: Sorry, it's `tcp::iostream`. i.e. `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream`

Comment: @Immueggpain accorind to this http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Is-boost-asio-ip-tcp-iostream-thread-safe-td4622815.html its not thread-safe too.

Comment: "create different istream and ostream objects which wrap the same 
underlying raw socket descriptor" that seems to be a solution.

Comment: I'll mark your answer accepted, but could you update it to show us a little more on how to combine `tcp::iostream` with `boost::asio`? Or give a link to start with? And also that would fully answer my questions.

Comment: @Immueggpain sorry according to this example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html you are doing it right (`iostream` listening looks hacky for me since i never used it)

Comment: Listening should not be the problem here.